# How to not touch my DI container for every new method in Api Controller when using f#

Tags: dependency-injection, f#

I am trying to wrap my head around how to handle DI in F# when using WebApi with something like Ninject.

For example, in C# when i wire up my container I would simply tell the DI what the type resolves to, for example:

```
kernel.Bind<ISomeInterface>().To<SomeClass>();
```

My Api Controllers will automatically wire this when required by the controllers constructor.

Great, now I can add methods to the interface & class all day long w/o touching the container again.

However in F# (unless i am doing this completely wrong) I create partial applications and then pass them to the controller, every time I add a method i have to wire up again at the container.  Maybe this is correct, I am not sure but it seems like a lot more wiring.

To clarify what I mean, lets take a typical REST Api. For each entity with CRUD - so for example:

Customer (Create, Read, Update, Delete).

Would I then have to inject each function into the controller?

So in this example, lets say that i have the service -> domain -> repo model:

```
let createCustomerFunc = createCustomerDomainFunc createCustomerRepoFunc
let getAllCustomersFunc = getAllCustomerDomainFunc getAllCustomerRepoFunc
let updateCustomerFunc cust = [...]
let deleteCustomerFunc id = [...]
let getSingleCustomerFunc id = [...]
```

Now in my container when i bind it, i would then do something like:

```
kernel.Bind<CustomerController>().To<CustomerController>()
.WithConstructorArgument(createCustomerFunc, getAllCustomerFunc, etc...) 
|> ignore
```

Now if i add method:  GetActiveCustomers I would then have to modify my code above to pass in the new partial application?

That feels ... wrong - am i simply approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a DI Container provides some advantages, as well as some disadvantages.

The major advantage is that, if [you have a large code base, you can use convention over configuration](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer) to wire up all the dependencies. With convention over configuration, you also get the benefit that your code will have to be more consistent, because it has to follow conventions.

There are several disadvantages, though. The most immediate is that you lose the [rapid feedback from the compiler](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/29/Feedbackmechanismsandtradeoffs). You can much easier make a change to your system, and while everything compiles, the system fails at run-time. Some people hope that you can ask a DI Container to self-diagnose, but [you can't](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/21/TestingContainerConfigurations).

Another, less apparent, disadvantage of using a DI Container is that it becomes too easy, as you say, to simply add more members to Controllers, etc. This actually increases coupling, or reduces cohesion, but the Reflection-based automation provided by DI Containers hides this problem from you.

Since I believe that the disadvantages outweigh the advantages, I recommend that you use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) instead of DI Containers.

This goes for Object-Oriented Programming in C#, Visual Basic .NET, or Java, but applies equally to Functional Programming in F#.

In an unmixed Functional F# code base, I wouldn't use classes or interfaces at all; instead, I'd only compose functions together.

In a mixed code base with e.g. ASP.NET Web API, I'd cross the bridge between OOP and FP as quickly as possible. As I explain in my [Test-Driven Development with F#](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/mock-fsharp-tdd) talk ([expanded material available on Pluralsight](http://bit.ly/1Hhru7l)), I'd inject a function into a Controller like this:

```
type ReservationsController(imp) =
    inherit ApiController()
    member this.Post(rendition : ReservationRendition) : IHttpActionResult =
        match imp rendition with
        | Failure(ValidationError msg) -> this.BadRequest msg :> _
        | Failure CapacityExceeded -> this.StatusCode HttpStatusCode.Forbidden :> _
        | Success () -> this.Ok () :> _
```

That's the *entire* code base of that Controller. All behaviour is implemented by `imp`.

In the startup code of the application, `imp` is composed like this:

```
let imp =
    Validate.reservationValid
    >> Rop.bind (Capacity.check 10 SqlGateway.getReservedSeats)
    >> Rop.map SqlGateway.saveReservation
```

You may argue that the above `ReservationsController` only defines a single `Post` method. What if a Controller has to expose more methods?

In that case, inject an implementation function *per* method. In a REST API, any Controller only ought to have 2-3 methods anyway, so that means, in effect, 2-3 dependencies. In my opinion, that's a perfectly acceptable number of dependencies.

---

The reason for the 2-3 method maximum is that in proper RESTful design, resources tend to follow a few interaction patterns:

- `GET`
- `POST`
- `POST`, `GET`
- `PUT`, `GET`
- `DELETE`, `GET`
- `PUT`, `DELETE`, `GET`

The full combination (`POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE`) is a REST design smell, but all of that is an entirely different discussion.

Comment: good point on the late binding issues with a DI Container.  Either way at first it felt awkward but now not so much after finishing V1 - no interfaces, pure functional -- and it was a lot less hassle in the end :-)

Comment: In that talk (the "Look No Mocks" one), you never tested the `imp` function itself. If you did, the function would have ended up with another 3 or 4 parameters (depending on how you want to wire it), and that's just for the very simple toy example. Ultimately, such "root" functions end up with a gazillion parameters (transitive closure of all dependencies down the tree), which is what the original question was actually about.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Had I been doing something like the above in C# with a DI Container involved, I likewise wouldn't have felt compelled to unit test the integration, but if I had, I could. There are plenty of (C#) examples of that in my [Outside-In Test-Driven Development](http://bit.ly/outside-in-tdd) Pluralsight course, and it doesn't change the design. This conclusion also holds for F#. At *Progressive F# Tutorials 2014* in London, I showed the same sort of integration tests, written in F#, for the above `imp` function, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Is there a video of the _Progressive F# Tutorials_ talk? Or at least slide deck?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin There isn't, and slides will not help you, but I'll see if I can write down the essentials...

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Done: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/21/integration-testing-composed-functions

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you are using functional code style in a object oriented framework. Since WebAPI required you to instantiate a controller, you have to bridge the OO to functional approach somehow.

Setting function values in a DI container is a rather awkward approach, since you have to manually bind to the constructor arguments. I would recommend an adapter pattern based approach, that is create a class to wrap the (static) function calls.

```
pub type CustomerFunctionAdapter() =
     member x.CreateCustomer = createCustomerFunc
     member x.GetAllCustomers = getAllCustomersFunc
     // ...
```

and still bind with

```
kernel.Bind<ISomeInterface>().To<CustomerFunctionAdapter>();
```

This way, your changes and additions are in CustomerFunctionAdapter, rather that in your DI bindings.